# I18n with_translation and where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n, globalize3

I'm trying to run a query on table Testimonials which has a Translation Table TestimonialTranslations.

The Following query works like a charm:

```
Testimonial.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

When I change the query to:

```
Testimonial.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(:alias => "test").first
```

**It doesn't return any values?**

A record exists where the where class is true:

```
=> [#<Testimonial id: 1, title: "Test", person: "", image_uid: nil, content: "<p>zfzefzfLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a...", interest_group: "", created_at: "2015-01-15 11:48:11", updated_at: "2015-01-15 11:48:11", job: "", overview: true, content_short: "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci...", hidden: false, hide_image: false, alias: "test">]
```

I know 100% sure that the language is "nl" and that it returns a query when I run:

```
Testimonial.with_translations(I18n.locale)
```

These are my specs:

- ruby 1.9.3p550 (2014-10-27 revision 48165) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]
- Rails 3.2.19

**EDIT 1:**

I'm going to leave this open for a while but as far as I can see it is not possible to add a where to the with_translations query that will go and look in the translation table.

With this knowledge I will need to do 2 querys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with `with_translated_attribute` ?

Comment: That worked t.b.h. @testimonial = Testimonial.with_translated_attribute(:alias, params[:id].downcase, I18n.locale).first

Answer (score 2):

you could try to add `to_sql` in order to check what sql query is generating

```
Testimonial.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(:alias => "test").to_sql
```

Comment: "SELECT \"testimonials\".* FROM \"testimonials\"  WHERE \"testimonial_translations\".\"locale\" = 'nl' AND \"testimonials\".\"alias\" = 'test'" It seems to be doing the where on the testimonials instead of on the testimonials_translations

Comment: Are you using globalize gem? Checking the code a little bit, I think you could use the method `with_translated_attribute`.

Comment: Here is the line: https://github.com/globalize/globalize/blob/eccb924ac9641b52399f22525b0e3ec004739f4c/lib/globalize/active_record/class_methods.rb#L22